# PAYPAL:Cant to login sandbox paypal test account..!

Tags: php, paypal

I used the sandbox paypal  url in my  coding like this...

form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"

But i cant to login in my sandbox paypal account and how to create the sandbox paypal account.

i used the following link for create an account.

**https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts**

I want the webscr url for sandbox paypal account login.

Comment: Paypal now requires developers to login to sandbox using their Paypal account only. Login using your Paypal account credentials https://developer.paypal.com/. Once logged in, you should be able to setup test accounts.

Comment: ok thank u.. but i want to login to my account via this url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: I don't think you need to login using that URL. If you are trying to test payments using sandbox then you need to be logged in to developer.paypal.com in a tab of the same browser which you are using for testing the payment.

Comment: ok thank you i Created my sandbox paypal account in developer.paypal.com....